# Segmenting on Arcs from DWG File

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I have an application using the Forge Viewer displaying converted ACAD dwg files.  The short description is that I need to take specific polylines out of the dwg file source and use the Edit2D extension to draw them as polygons over the background.  I have this working, but arcs are causing some issues right now.  This doesn't have to be perfect but it should be decently the same shape.  In most cases it is just drawing a line from the start to the end of the arc (and I understand why, see code below) but in other cases it's significantly segmenting the arc and I'm not sure why.

I start by finding the id's of the polylines based on their layer and then getting the fragment ids (this is working fine).  Then I get the vertexes for the polyline like this:

```
export function getVertexesById(
  viewer: Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D,
  frags: Autodesk.Viewing.Private.FragmentList,
  fragIds: number[],
  dbId: number
): Point[] {
  // We need to also get the center points of arcs as lines seem to be drawn to them in the callbacks for some
  // reason.  Center points should later be removed from the point array, so we don't get strange spikes on our shapes.
  const polyPoints: Point[] = [];
  const centers: Point[] = [];

  fragIds.forEach((fid) => {
    const mesh = frags.getVizmesh(fid);
    const vbr = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.VertexBufferReader(
      mesh.geometry,
      viewer.impl.use2dInstancing
    );
    vbr.enumGeomsForObject(dbId, {
      onLineSegment(
        x1: number,
        y1: number,
        x2: number,
        y2: number,
        _vpId: number
      ) {
        checkAddPoint(polyPoints, { x: x1, y: y1, z: 0 });
        checkAddPoint(polyPoints, { x: x2, y: y2, z: 0 });
      },
      onCircularArc: function (cx, cy, start, end, radius, _vpId) {
        centers.push({ x: cx, y: cy, z: 0 });
      },
      onEllipticalArc: function (
        cx,
        cy,
        start,
        end,
        major,
        minor,
        tilt,
        _vpId
      ) {
        centers.push({ x: cx, y: cy, z: 0 });
      },
      onOneTriangle: function (x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, _vpId) {
        checkAddPoint(polyPoints, { x: x1, y: y1, z: 0 });
        checkAddPoint(polyPoints, { x: x2, y: y2, z: 0 });
        checkAddPoint(polyPoints, { x: x3, y: y3, z: 0 });
      },
      onTexQuad: function (cx, cy, width, height, rotation, _vpId) {
        centers.push({ x: cx, y: cy, z: 0 });
      },
    });
  });

  centers.forEach((c) => {
    checkRemovePoint(polyPoints, { x: c.x, y: c.y, z: 0 });
  });

  return polyPoints;
}
```

The functions `checkAddPoint` and `checkRemovePoint` are just helper functions that make sure we don't duplicate points and take into account rounding (so we don't get two points that are say 0,0,0 and 0,0.00001,0.

I then use those points to draw with the Edit2D extension.  So what I would expect here is that it creates a series of points that would draw along all the straight lines of the polyline and when it gets to an arc it just draws from one endpoint to the other.  That is *mostly* what I see.

Here is an example file as it looks in ACAD:

[image: ACAD File]

Notice there are a handful of breaks in the arc around the outside of the room.  What I get when I do the above process is this:

[image: Viewer]

Notice all along the top I get what I would expect.  However, along the bottom in 2 places I get a huge number of segments all along the line.

I looked back at the ACAD file and exploded the polyline and looked at it as much as I know how and I can't find anything different about those two segments vs. the other that would indicate why it acts differently.

What would be really awesome is if there is an easy way to just segment along an arc say every x units and have it return that but I'm not expecting that here, I just want to know why it is treating these differently.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

I should also mention that I have logged the creation routine and the only things in this that are ever hit are the `onLineSegment` and `onCircularArc`.  As you see, the circular arc one only checks to make sure we don't have the center point in the list, so all of these extra points are for some reason being read in the line segment section.

Comment: Sorry for letting you wait. From your latest editing, it sounds the entity (which looks like arc) actually hit onLineSegment with segments of lines, so it draws the lines. I doubt this entity is actually lines for some special reasons. Have you checked its type in AutoCAD?

Comment: In addition, what would it be if using my code snippet at the blog? https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/dump-geometries-2d-curve . If the reality is the same, could you share a copy of the drawing for us to investigate?

Comment: I am (knowingly) skipping the circular arc sections and only handling segments, mainly because it's being drawn with Edit2D extension which doesn't seem to to arcs well.  This is fine for now, but as mentioned it gets segmented in certain cases only.  Comparing dwg to forge viewer in the images, the top curve is only segmented where the polyline is segmented in cad.  The bottom section is segmented MUCH more.  I can't see any difference in cad.  I can share the dwg, where would you like me to send it?  Also I did use that link as an example to develop what I have so far.

Comment: you can send the drawing to forge.help AT autodesk.com, referring to the Stackoverflow post. thank you.